# skip function execution using before plugin

Tags: admin, magento2.2, redirect, plugin, response

I'm overriding the controller `Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Validate::execute()` using before-plugin so I can perform some checks before magento validate using this function. If certain condition met, I want to return an error response from my before-plugin and skip the execution of main execute action. For this, I write the code below.

```
<!-- app/code/[vendor]/[module]/etc/di.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Validate">
        <plugin name="admin_user_validate_controller_plugin" type="[vendor]\[module]\Plugin\AdminUserValidateControllerPlugin" sortOrder="20"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

and here is my plugin.

```
namespace [vendor]\[module]\Plugin;

class AdminUserValidateControllerPlugin
{            
    public function beforeExecute(\Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Validate $subject)
    {
        $response = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $response->setError(0);
        $errors = null;

        if([some_custom_validation_checks_return_false]) {
            $error = "some_error_message"; 
            $subject->messageManager->addError($error);

            $response->setError(1);
            $subject->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
            $response->setHtmlMessage($subject->_view->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml());
            $subject->getResponse()->representJson($response->toJson()); 
        }
    }
}
```

**Question#1:** I was expecting it to return my error message in response of ajax call of validation controller, but it redirects to admin_dashboard page with my error message. How can I make it correct so my plugin will respond.

**Question#2:** After responding via ajax, how can we make it so magento stop further execution of main function. Also can we achieve it? That is, can we exit/die further execution in before-plugin in a proper way?

Thank you.

Comment: have you found a solution using before plugin or you went with preference?

Comment: @Radu not yet, had to go for conventional preference method to override the function.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can achieve this functionality via plugins as well

using around you can easily do it for example:

```
namespace [vendor]\[module]\Plugin;

class AdminUserValidateControllerPlugin
{            
    public function aroundExecute(Validate $subject, \Closure $proceed) {

        // place your logic here what you want
        if(your condition not mat and want to stop execution) {

            //save error message
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('render error'));
            // return using ResultFactory some thing like that
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->redirect->getRefererUrl());

            return $resultRedirect; // or in case of Ajax request you can return json response from here
        }
        // else case proceed to acttul function or other plugin
        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

Also can break further processing in befor pugin you can just throw exception if condition mat and plugin will stop further processing.

Comment: +++1 Working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure whether I can use plugin or not as per my functionality requirement. So as a workaround, I'm using preference. Would love to hear from someone the plugin_way of doing this.
Preference way is as follow. Hope this helps someone.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">    
    <preference for="Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Validate" type="[vendor]\[module]\Controller\Rewrite\Adminhtml\User\Validate" />
</config>
```

And the rewritten controller is as follow.

```
namespace [vendor]\[module]\Controller\Rewrite\Adminhtml\User;

class Validate extends \Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Validate
{
    /**
     * AJAX customer validation action
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $response = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $response->setError(0);
        $errors = null;
        $userId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('user_id');
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

        if([some_validation_criteria_fails]) {
            $err = "You error message";
            $errors[] = $err; 
        }else{

            try {
                /** @var $model \Magento\User\Model\User */
                $model = $this->_userFactory->create()->load($userId);
                $model->setData($this->_getAdminUserData($data));
                $errors = $model->validate();
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception $exception) {
                /* @var $error Error */
                foreach ($exception->getMessages(\Magento\Framework\Message\MessageInterface::TYPE_ERROR) as $error) {
                    $errors[] = $error->getText();
                }
            }

        }

        if ($errors !== true && !empty($errors)) {
            foreach ($errors as $error) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($error);
            }
            $response->setError(1);
            $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
            $response->setHtmlMessage($this->_view->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml());
        }

        $this->getResponse()->representJson($response->toJson());
    }

}
?>
```

This will return error message as per your validation scenario.